# Test statistics, angles made by random vectors in the plane relative to axis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $Y_i$ be angles made by random vectors in the plane relative to some reference axis.
What should I use as my test statistics to test the hypothesis that my $Y$ are independently and uniformly distributed between 0 and $2\pi$, if suppose that there is clustering about the direction 0 and $\pi$?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat the angles as your random variates, and test acceptance for the hypothesis that they are uniformly distributed on the allowable interval, then the Kolmogorov-Smyrnov test statistic is the one to use.

See section 14.3 of Numerical Recipes by Press, Teulkowski, et. al. for details on how to use this statistic.